# Display date in MM/dd/yyyy format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am working on an MVC 5.2 application with default culture of en-GB, which has default ShortDatePattern of dd/MM/yyyy. I want to change the date pattern to MM/dd/yyyy for view/edit models.

It's working fine when displaying the model. However facing issues when displaying date in edit mode. Below is my code -
**ViewModel**

```
[Display(Name="License Renewal Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
public DateTime LicenseRenewalDate { get; set; }
```

**.cshtml**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LicenseRenewalDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LicenseRenewalDate, "", new { @class="text-danger" })
```

Below is the screen-shot from Edit mode - 
[image]

As you can see, default date pattern is shown as dd/MM/yyyy in the edit box and date-picker control doesn't allow me to change it.
How can I set the date-picker control to have default date pattern of MM/dd/yyyy?

FYI, I am using

```
jQuery.Validation version - 1.11.1 and 
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation version - 3.2.3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define default culture in Web.Config

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-en" />
```

OR

We can make other data types such as  DateTime get their own custom editor, just by placing a partial View in the  EditorTemplates folder under the Sharedfolder  and naming it after the target data type.   You will need to create this folder yourself since it is not automatically added to the project.

A  DateTime.cshtml might look like this …

```
@model  DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : 

string.Empty),new { @class = "datePicker" , 

@readonly = "readonly"})
```

along with a snippet of jQuery code like this to associate the jQuery UI date picker to the class datePicker

```
<script>

     $(function () {

         $(".datePicker").datepicker({

            showOn: "button",

             buttonImage:  "/images/calendar-icon.png",

             buttonImageOnly: true,

            buttonText: "Select date"

         });

     });

</script>
```

Comment: The web.config option didn't work. Then I tried with DateTime EdiotrTemplate, but it looks like, it's not being called. I have added DateTime.cshtml as you suggested in \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml

Comment: I got it working by removing [DataType(DataType.Date)] from ViewModel property. This attribute renders the input control with type=date. Custom EditorTemplate for DateTime doesn't work for input controls with type="date".